# How to check if a string of 7 random letters can form a word that exists in a file

Tags: java, file

I've been trying to figure out the best possible method to tackle this problem I'm having, so far no luck.

I have a file called "dict.txt" which is about 2MB in size and contains a list of acceptable words.

Using a randomly generated string of 7 letters, I want to see if I can form a word from the file using those letters, in the fastest way possible.

I cannot seem to come up with a good method for solving this problem , so if anyone could help me that would great! 
The language I'm using is Java

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Post your actual try on this, and point us on where you're stuck

Comment: the words in dict.txt are only 7 letters? if not, the first step would be filtering for those

Comment: For every word in the dictionary, count the individual letters (such that `exceeds` => `c * 1, d * 1, e * 3, s * 1, x * 1`). Then you can do a check whether your random letters match the distribution of each word.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "form a word using those letters"? Can each of those 7 letter only be used once? Does forming a word using a subset of those letters also count?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to implement would be to filter the `txt` file to keep only seven-letter words, and making a `HashSet<String>` out of strings constructed by sorting the letters of the word alphabetically. For example, if the dictionary contains words

```
kickbox
jackpot
squeeze
```

you would put words

```
bcikkox
acjkopt
eeeqsuz
```

Sort the letters of the incoming word and query the set to see if there are any matches. For example, if your random sequence is `tajpkco` you would sort its letters to `acjkopt`, and find that you can form a word from that combination.

If you also need to find out which seven-letter words you could construct from these letters, use a hash map to a list of strings, because multiple words may be produced from the same set of letters.

Note that if you are planning to continue generating a random sequence until you hit a "valid" one, the process may take a while. You would be better off storing all "valid" sequences upfront, picking one at random, and then performing a random shuffle on the sequence that you picked, for a much faster selection.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at [Suffix Trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree).

You would first index your dictionary as a suffix tree and then traverse the tree to check if a word exists on not.